# Add Comment option is missing in ROR Blog sample application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs

ROR Sample Application URL - http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-create-a-blog-from-scratch-using-ruby-on-rails/

I tried above reference for creating a blog application using Ruby on Rails.
Everything is working fine except the option "Add Comment" in show page of a Post.

As per the reference URL "Add Comment" will be there in Show page itself. But in my local browser I am not able to see it.

**Note** : I am using Rails 3.1.3 with back end of PostgreSQL 9.0.5

Comment: Show us some of your code. Maybe we'll spot errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably missed something in the code (obvious, I know), I would suggest rolling back to a working model without comments and following the guide from there.

This guide is a copy of the sample blog guide found at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html so I would suggest following the official guide as it probably explains in more detail and covers topics based on community feedback. I have found these guides to be the most up-to-date resource for rails on the web.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is based on RoR 2. You are using Rails 3.1.3, which means that this tutorial won't work.

As suggested, I would go with the official guide : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3.0 changed how ERB tags (`<%`) are interpreted. You now need to use `<%=` with any blocks that are capturing output. If you were running this in 3.0.x, you would see deprecation warnings, but 3.1.x assumes you have already made the changes and silently fails.

```
<% form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
```

would become:

```
<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
```